# EF Core many to many relation on single column with composite primary key

Tags: many-to-many, relationship, ef-core-7.0

I have following tables with composite primary keys (ID, Lang) and have many to many relation through **CompanyCustomers** table
[image: Tables and relations]

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Companies").HasKey(pk => new { pk.ID, pk.Lang });

            });



            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Customers").HasKey(pk => new { pk.ID, pk.Lang });

            });



            modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyCustomer>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("CompanyCustomers").HasKey(pk => new { pk.CompanyID, pk.CustomerID });

            });
```

1. How to configure many to many relation?
2. How to write Linq (method syntax) to **INNER** join and return **Customers** of the company (following is method signature

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCompanyCustomers(int companyId, string lang)
{
    // var result = _db.Companies.Join(...).Select(s=> s.Customer).ToList();
}
```

Comment: `CompanyCustomer` must have 2 x 2 foreign key properties to refer to both entities.

Comment: @GertArnold you mean to say, that is not possible as shown in the picture?